# Change Modal Image on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a modal pop up box, so that when I click on an icon, a different image pops up. I've only been able to make the same icon pop up instead of a different image. I'm basically a total beginner with JS, so I'm not sure what some of the code means or why it's needed. I'm trying to replace "cameraicon.svg" with "canon.png".

This is what I have so far:

```
    <img id="myImg" src="Images/cameraicon.svg" alt="This photo...." width="30" height="30">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <img src="Images/canon.png" id="canon">

  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
function changeImage(img) {
    document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace("myImg", "canon");
}
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("canon");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: There is no JQuery in here, its all pure JS. When you have included JQuery make use of it - **Its a lifesaver**

Comment: `document.getElementById("img").src` I can't see any element with id as `img`. This will not work.  Which image are you trying to target?

Comment: Oops! I suppose I meant JS. I'm trying to replace "myImg" with "canon". I'm just not sure where anything is supposed to go since I don't understand the code.

Comment: The code you're using opens a modal containing an image, and switches the image to be the same as the link that was clicked.  There's also some redundant code in there (The `changeImage` function doesn't seem to do anything).  Is this the desired outcome?

Comment: Hmm ok, I will write a JQuery for all this. Suggest just remove all this JS. Since most of it wouldn't even work. Clean the mess. Is a JQuery solution fine with you ?

Comment: @JordanBurnett I'm trying to change the image to be different than the link that was clicked. I'm actually not sure which code is redundant and what is necessary as well. Very much a raw beginner.

Comment: Yes, I think that should be fine. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is going to be a ground-up rewrite so that it makes more sense than my original answer.

You've got your HTML all written and now you want to make it dynamic, which you'll do with javascript! You want to make a modal pop up when you click an image, which is very doable. We'll start with what you call "pseudocode," which is like code but it doesn't actually work because it's more like a logical explanation.

```
//pseudocode starts here
//first, let's create a variable and assign it to the original image's element
someImage = get the image html element

//tell javascript what to do when that element is clicked
someImage.onclick = function() {
    //executes when the element is clicked
    //at this point you'll already have which element was clicked on
    someImage.src = "new source";
}
```

First, we acquire the image's html element. Every html element has an `onclick` event. When that event is assigned to a function, it executes that function whenever the element is clicked. So, now let's write ourselves a real program! I'll be using the same html that you have above.

```
// real code starts here
// this gets the html element with id="realImg", which already exists on the page
var firstImg = document.getElementById("realImg");

//now we'll build a function
var imgSwitchFunction = function() {
    // assuming this function gets called when firstImg is clicked,
    //  we will simply change the source property of firstImg
    //  notice that there is not actually a "secondImg" variable
    //  and there doesn't need to be one in the html!
    firstImg.src = "Images/canon.png";
}

// this assigns our function to the element's onclick event,
//  meaning that it will be called when the element is clicked
firstImg.onclick = imgSwitchFunction;
```

Notice that this isn't very many lines of code at all to get the functionality you described in your question. The best way to code is the simple way!

If this answers your question, please accept is as the answer :)

Comment: Okay! I see. Also, right now I just inserted my image below <img class="modal-content" id="img01"> but I'm not sure if this is where it's supposed to go. Where should I place the image I'm wanting to change to?

Comment: Shouldn't matter where you place the image that you're trying to change to, since it's javascript you should just be able to find it (wherever it is) and then call your function to replace it

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer... will try and get you more here in a second

Comment: Let me know if you understand! If you have some more questions I can try to flush out a better explanation. The other answer you've got will get the job done as far as copy/pasting code goes, but it doesn't have to put the modal image on the page. Like above, you can just alter the source property! Javascript is fun

Comment: thank you for your help! I'm afraid I'm still pretty confused. Since everything looks and sounds the same to me, I'm afraid I'm changing/deleting the wrong parts, or adding in the wrong image files in the wrong places.

Comment: I'll write up a more linear answer here in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Change your functions as so:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("canon");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
function changeImage() {
  img.src = modalImg.src;
}

img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    changeImage();
}
```

Rest all should be fine. Moved all your variables to the top